# Have map rotate to be the direction you are looking

Tags: battlefield-3

In Battlefield 3 is there a way to have the map shown in the hub always point the direct you are facing?

So as you turn so does the map.

EDIT: I'm referring to when the map is enlarged by pressing 'M'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the Map is static but as you said you can zoom in or zoom out by pressing "M".